# Custom Domain not showing in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created an azure function application to move an application from another MVC app. The steps I took were the following:

1. Added Function App on a consumption plan
2. Published Function App
3. Removed Domain From Azure Web App that contained old application
4. Added Domain to Azure Function App.

The issue is that the portal does not show the custom domain. If I try to re-add it, it says it always added to an application. I have contacted support and they say they see it added to the Azure Function on https://resources.azure.com.

So my question is this a bug in the portal? I was just trying to manage it from the portal. Can we get the portal to show this correctly?

Here is the screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom domains are not yet supported for Dynamic Function plans. This support will come a bit later (no clear ETA to share at this point).

[Setting up a custom domain with an Azure Function app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515586/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-an-azure-function-app)

Comment: Since I have my CNAME pointed to it, it is working, is this dangerous and may stop working?

Comment: Here is the thing, the portal does let you add the custom domain and has been working. But for some reason the SSL binding just randomly stopped working. My big issue here with Azure in general, if this is not supported, then don't turn it on in the portal. It is not possible for us to know every little feature that is enabled or not, we can only do what it lets us and when it doesn't work, don't tell us it isn't supported.

Comment: FYI - @davidebbo commented on that answer in Nov '16 (after your comment @Jonathan) saying that it was supported.